# I keep getting a internal server error for my flask app for a web scraper

Tags: python, html, flask, web-scraping

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def job_scraper():
    url01 = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=Python%20%28Programming%20Language%29&location=Las%20Vegas%2C%20Nevada%2C%20United%20States&geoId=100293800&currentJobId=3477751834&position=7&pageNum=1"
    
    url_request_01 = requests.get(url01)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_request_01.text, 'html.parser')
    
    job_title_pull = soup.find_all(class_="base-search-card__title")
    job_subtitle_pull = soup.find_all(class_="base-search-card__subtitle")
    job_location_pull = soup.find_all(class_="job-search-card__location")
    job_date_pull = soup.find_all(class_="job-search-card__listdate")
    job_links = [job_link_pull['href'] for job_link_pull in soup.find_all('a', href=True, class_="base-card__full-link absolute top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-0 p-0 z-[2]")]
    
    job_title_data = [title.text.strip() for title in job_title_pull]
    job_subtitle_data = [subtitle.text.strip() for subtitle in job_subtitle_pull]
    job_location_data = [location.text.strip() for location in job_location_pull]
    job_date_data = [date.text.strip() for date in job_date_pull]

    data = {'title': job_title_data,
            'subtitle': job_subtitle_data,
            'location': job_location_data,
            'date': job_date_data,
            'link': job_links}

    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return render_template('index.html', table_html=df.to_html(classes='table table-striped', index=False))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5001)
```

**here is my html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your Web App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Your Data</h1>
    {{ table_html | safe }}
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the error**

```
applemacbookproa2289@APPLEs-MacBook-Pro-2 web-scraping-01 % python3 scraping.py
 * Serving Flask app 'scraping'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5001
 * Running on http://192.168.4.53:5001
Press CTRL+C to quit
[2024-01-12 10:03:36,006] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/applemacbookproa2289/Desktop/web-scraping-01/scraping.py", line 33, in job_scraper
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 733, in __init__
    mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 503, in dict_to_mgr
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 114, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = _extract_index(arrays)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 677, in _extract_index
    raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
192.168.4.53 - - [12/Jan/2024 10:03:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
[2024-01-12 10:04:22,869] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/applemacbookproa2289/Desktop/web-scraping-01/scraping.py", line 33, in job_scraper
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 733, in __init__
    mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 503, in dict_to_mgr
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 114, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = _extract_index(arrays)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 677, in _extract_index
    raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
192.168.4.53 - - [12/Jan/2024 10:04:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I tried a bunch of random solution already, but I can't figure out whats wrong. May you please point me in the right direction, as I am just testing this out. Once I am able to get the scrapped data to html, the next step for me is to take user input Job title and location to pull the data something similar to this.

```
jobtitle = input("Enter job title: ")
location = input("Enter job location: ")

url01 = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords="+jobtitle+"&location="+location+"&geoId=&trk=public_jobs_jobs-search-bar_search-submit&position=1&pageNum=0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that not every job has element with `class="job-search-card__listdate"` so you need to check for that:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url01 = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=Python%20%28Programming%20Language%29&location=Las%20Vegas%2C%20Nevada%2C%20United%20States&geoId=100293800&currentJobId=3477751834&position=7&pageNum=1"

url_request_01 = requests.get(url01)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_request_01.text, "html.parser")

job_title_pull = soup.find_all(class_="base-search-card__title")
job_subtitle_pull = soup.find_all(class_="base-search-card__subtitle")
job_location_pull = soup.find_all(class_="job-search-card__location")
job_date_pull = soup.find_all(class_="job-search-card__listdate")
job_links = [
    job_link_pull["href"]
    for job_link_pull in soup.find_all(
        "a",
        href=True,
        class_="base-card__full-link absolute top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-0 p-0 z-[2]",
    )
]

job_title_data = [title.text.strip() for title in job_title_pull]
job_subtitle_data = [subtitle.text.strip() for subtitle in job_subtitle_pull]
job_location_data = [location.text.strip() for location in job_location_pull]

job_date_data = [
    d.text.strip() if (d := job.select_one(".job-search-card__listdate")) else None
    for job in soup.select(".job-search-card")
]

data = {
    "title": job_title_data,
    "subtitle": job_subtitle_data,
    "location": job_location_data,
    "date": job_date_data,
    "link": job_links,
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                     title                                        subtitle       location          date                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              link
0                            Junior/Entry Level Software Developer(Remote)                                   SynergisticIT  Las Vegas, NV   1 month ago                            https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/junior-entry-level-software-developer-remote-at-synergisticit-3767588842?refId=6e6Ii6kYrj9B0Fhpi6T3ag%3D%3D&trackingId=gBXODO%2FGuULT55Q6dJzufw%3D%3D&position=1&pageNum=0&trk=public_jobs_jserp-result_search-card
1                                     Junior Software Development Engineer  Team Remotely Inc: Talent Solution Reimagined!  Las Vegas, NV          None  https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/junior-software-development-engineer-at-team-remotely-inc-talent-solution-reimagined%21-3805052007?refId=6e6Ii6kYrj9B0Fhpi6T3ag%3D%3D&trackingId=FXvU%2FHLIKDYVFT6Pjv8miA%3D%3D&position=2&pageNum=0&trk=public_jobs_jserp-result_search-card
2                                           Backend Developer(Entry Level)                                   SynergisticIT  Las Vegas, NV   3 weeks ago                                             https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/backend-developer-entry-level-at-synergisticit-3784401022?refId=6e6Ii6kYrj9B0Fhpi6T3ag%3D%3D&trackingId=BzXsFKHN1CCduvAj2TWNNA%3D%3D&position=3&pageNum=0&trk=public_jobs_jserp-result_search-card
3                                                 Junior Software Engineer                                   SynergisticIT  Las Vegas, NV   1 month ago                                                https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/junior-software-engineer-at-synergisticit-3767595083?refId=6e6Ii6kYrj9B0Fhpi6T3ag%3D%3D&trackingId=v6IbHxai%2Bjh7sUI6kl0PLA%3D%3D&position=4&pageNum=0&trk=public_jobs_jserp-result_search-card
4                             Data Scientist(Rermote) - Junior/Entry Level                                   SynergisticIT  Las Vegas, NV    1 week ago                               https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/data-scientist-rermote-junior-entry-level-at-synergisticit-3792903797?refId=6e6Ii6kYrj9B0Fhpi6T3ag%3D%3D&trackingId=s%2BTFVT3a5IxYwJ4UGrhHdg%3D%3D&position=5&pageNum=0&trk=public_jobs_jserp-result_search-card

...
```

Comment: The issue isn't that its not scrapping the data its more along the lines that i cant get it to display on html when I run flask.

Comment: Your exception did help in getting pass the error thank you, i was also able to figure out how to pass the data to html as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue here is my solution

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route("/")
    def job_scraper():
        url01 = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=Python%20%28Programming%20Language%29&location=Las%20Vegas%2C%20Nevada%2C%20United%20States&geoId=100293800&currentJobId=3477751834&position=7&pageNum=1"
        
        url_request_01 = requests.get(url01)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url_request_01.text, 'html.parser')
        
        job_title_pull = soup.find_all(class_="base-search-card__title")
        job_subtitle_pull = soup.find_all(class_="base-search-card__subtitle")
        job_location_pull = soup.find_all(class_="job-search-card__location")
        job_date_pull = soup.find_all(class_="job-search-card__listdate")
        job_links = [job_link_pull['href'] for job_link_pull in soup.find_all('a', href=True, class_="base-card__full-link absolute top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-0 p-0 z-[2]")]
        
        job_title_data = [title.text.strip() for title in job_title_pull]
        job_subtitle_data = [subtitle.text.strip() for subtitle in job_subtitle_pull]
        job_location_data = [location.text.strip() for location in job_location_pull]
        job_date_data = [
        d.text.strip() if (d := job.select_one(".job-search-card__listdate")) else None
        for job in soup.select(".job-search-card")]
        data = {'title': job_title_data,
            'subtitle': job_subtitle_data,
            'location': job_location_data,
            'link': job_date_data,
            'date': job_date_data}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df_html = df.to_html(table_id="table")
        
        
        return render_template('index.html', df=df, df_html = df_html)
        
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5001)
```

Here is the code for HTML to loop through the data frame created in python

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your Web App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th> <!-- Close the th tag properly -->
        </tr>
        {% for cell in df.title %}
        <tr>
            <td> {{ cell }} </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <h1>Your Data1</h1>
</body>
</html>
```